# The smallest Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, dg.differential-geometry

For $g\geq 2$, let $M_g$ be the moduli space of genus $g$ hyperbolic surfaces, and let $\lambda_1(S_x): M_g \to \mathbb{R}$ be the smallest eigenvalue of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the surface $S_x$ parametrized by a point $x\in M_g$.  Is there anything known about how the values of $\lambda_1$ are distributed when viewed as a function on moduli space?  For example, does the volume of the set of surfaces with  $\lambda_1(S_x)<\varepsilon$ go to zero rapidly as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Comment: Volume with respect to which metric? Two metrics that people consider are the Weil-Petersson and Teichmuller metrics. 

Comment: I have not seen too many results on Teichmuller volumes...

Answer (score 5):

Not anywhere near as much as known as one might like, but for enlightenment on your specific question see M. Mirzakhani's recent preprint on arXiv.org:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2167v1